# Play streaming audio in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, streaming, web-audio-api

I'm currently using `node-lame` to encode a raw PCM input stream, and I have the following code in Node.JS that successfully outputs binary MP3 chunks:

```
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  encoded.pipe(res);
});
```

I try to request this code inside of my front-end interface with code like the following:

```
var audio = new Audio('http://localhost:8000/a.mp3'); // the above
audio.play();
```

However, as the audio source is a continuous input stream, the content just keeps getting downloaded without end:

[image: Endless downloading]

Instead, I want to be able to play the chunks as they are downloaded.

I can access `http://localhost:8000/a.mp3` in an application like VLC or Quicktime Player, and the audio delivery works fine; I'm just stumped as to how to best do this on the web.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource

Answer (score 6):

This code works for us:

```
<audio id="music" preload="all">
   <source src="http://localhost:8000/a.mp3">
</audio>
<script>
  let music = document.getElementById('music');
  music.play();
</script>
```